# Cannot run deployd (http://deployd.com/) on my mac

Tags: macos, deployd

I need to create api by deployd but cannot open it on the localhost.
This is my code

```
Variss-Air:nodeServer manjarb$ dpd create sportsstore
to start your app:
    $ cd sportsstore
    $ dpd
Variss-Air:nodeServer manjarb$ cd sportsstore
Variss-Air:sportsstore manjarb$ dpd -d
starting deployd v0.8.4...
listening on port 2403
type help for a list of commands
dpd > bye
Variss-Air:sportsstore manjarb$
```

But When it open the browser(Google chrome).
On this address.

```
http://localhost:2403/dashboard/
```

I always got this

```
This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Hide details
Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.
```

So anyone knows how to fix it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From your terminal log, it looks like you're terminating the `dpd` program and then trying to access the dashboard.  You have to have `dpd` running if you want the dashboard or API to be accessible.

I'm actually working through the same book as you, Pro AngularJS? Here is the steps for getting deployd working:

```
$ cd deployd
$ dpd create sportsstore
$ cd sportsstore
$ dpd -p 5500 app.dpd
dpd > dashboard
```

The last line should bring up the dashboard in your default browser.  Like I said above you must keep `dpd` running in the terminal to access the dashboard and the API.

You could run this command instead:

```
$ dpd -p 5500 app.dpd &
```

The ampersand (&) at the end will make the process run in the background, so you can then feel free to close the terminal or continue using it for other things.

Answer (score 0):

I used the same solution as ToastyMallows.  However, the first time I tried it, it failed.  But, when I added sudo to the last terminal command, it worked.  Other discussions I found led me to believe it may be a permission problem with Mongo (which I haven't solved yet).  Anyhow, the following worked for me:

```
$ cd deployd
$ dpd create sportsstore
$ cd sportsstore
$ sudo dpd -p 5500 app.dpd
Password: 
dpd > dashboard
```